# de Rham theorem for tempered distribution

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory, harmonic-analysis

I am wondering if the following statement holds.

> If $u\in \mathscr{S}'$ and  $u=\nabla p$ for some $p\in \mathscr{D}'$, then $p$ is in $\mathscr{S}'$.

Here $\mathscr{S}'$ is the space of tempered distributions and $\mathscr{D}'$ is the space of distributions.

I raised this question when I want to show the following claim:

> If $u\in \mathscr{S}'$ satisfies $\left< u,\Phi\right>=0$ for all $\Phi \in \mathscr{S}$ with $\mathrm{div}\, \Phi=0$, then there exists $p\in \mathscr{S}'$ such that $u=\nabla p$ in $\mathscr{S}'$.

Another guess for my question is based on the generalized Lions' lemma:

> If $f\in \mathscr{D}'$ and $\nabla f \in H^{-1}$, then $f\in L^2$.

Thank you for your time.